# Import data into multiple tables from excel sheet in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I am able to populate excel sheet's data into a datatable , that table is ***tempInput (sql fiddle)***
Now from that table I want to split data into two tables ***tbl1,tbl2 (fiddle)***

I am facing problem while inserting into tbl2.. let me show you those tables first

```
create table tempInput
(
  question_text nvarchar(100),
  description nvarchar(100),
  option_1 nvarchar(20),
  option_2 nvarchar(20),
  option_3 nvarchar(20),
  option_4 nvarchar(20),
  right_option nvarchar(50)
 )



create table tbl1
 (
  question_id int primary key identity(1,1),
  name nvarchar(100),
  description nvarchar(100)
  )

create table tbl2
 (
     option_id int IDENTITY(1,1) primary key ,
     option_text nvarchar(30),
     is_right_option bit,
     question_id int
 )
```

lets populate some sample data into **tempInput**

[image]

now I have to split sampleInput's data into two tables as follows..
[image]

[image]

How can I do that, please find it  **[here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/63a3c/1)**

Comment: You need to `UNPIVOT` your option values to get them as rows. You will also have to use a string split function to determine which one is right option, and join by it's value.

Comment: @EzequielLópezPetrucci working on it thanks :)

Comment: I am travelling can't type the exact code but I have worked on this kind of requirement earlier. Below is a gist of a code, try to implement this:-  TableA is straight forward and for table b use the following code

Comment: Part1 for table 2:With cte as(
select Question_text,
description, option_1, option_2, option_3, Option_4,
 Substring(right_option, 1,Charindex(',', right_option)-1) as RightOption_1,
Substring(right_option, Charindex(',', right_option)+1, LEN(right_option))as RightOption_2
from sourcetbl)

Comment: Part2 for table 2:- Select
b.option_id,
 option_1 as Option_test,
case when option_1 = RightOption_1 then 'True' else 'False'
from cte a inner join tbl1 b on a.question_test = b.name and a.description = b.description
union all
Select
b.option_id,
 option_2 as Option_test,
case when option_2 = RightOption_2 then 'True' else 'False'
from cte a inner join tbl1 b on a.question_test = b.name and a.description = b.description

Comment: Union all will help you to pivot columns to rows.

Comment: Thanks for you help sir @mehtat_90